# I want to turn the back of my credit card. Not with Focus

Tags: css

I have a credit card component. It works when there is a hover effect, but does not work in the focus part (CCV) of the corresponding Input. How can I do it?

Component Full Codes:
https://codepen.io/veronicadev/pen/VXqZgR (not my codes)

HTML Element

```
<input-mask id="special-cvc-input" v-model="cardCvc" type="text" mask="999"></input-mask>
```

Working Hover CSS Codes

```
.card:hover .card__front {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -moz-transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.card:hover .card__back {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg);
  -moz-transform: rotateY(0deg);
}
```

Not Working Focus CSS Codes

```
#special-cvc-input:focus .card_front{
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -moz-transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

#special-cvc-input:focus .card__back{
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg);
  -moz-transform: rotateY(0deg);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
.card:hover .card__front
```

on

```
#special-cvc-input:focus + .card .card__back
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/c7ehr6tm/ This my simple code, not working your example. Please modify JSFiddle. I need this code.

Comment: Is it okay to use js? Cuz input and card are on different levels in hierarchy which mean there is not simple way (I think) to achieve this in CSS the way you want... 
Here I did this in JS: https://jsfiddle.net/exavujd5/